# Changing the value of a variable in Linux kernel module programming

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel

I have a problem when trying to program a character device module.

I have a struct with an array of unsigned chars in it called "data".

```
struct my_char_device
{
    unsigned char* data;
    ...
};
```

I use kmalloc to allocate memory for the array and it works just fine. I use copy_from_user and copy_to_user and everything works like it should.

The problem starts when I'm trying to go byte by byte and change the values inside the array:

```
    for(i = 0;i<count;i++)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "data[%d] is changing from %d to ", i, ((struct my_char_device *)filp->private_data)->data[i]);
        ((struct my_char_device *)filp->private_data)->data[i] =(unsigned char) (((unsigned int)((((struct my_char_device *)filp->private_data)->enc_key * 3) + ((struct my_char_device *)filp->private_data)->data[i])) % 127);
        printk(KERN_INFO "%d\n",((struct my_char_device *)filp->private_data)->data[i]);
    }
```

`enc_key` is an unsigned char. I want to multiply it by 3, add the current value of `data[i]` ,take modulus 127 to the outcome and store it in `data[i]` right before I read it out to the user.

This is the outcome in dmesg when I'm trying to read the letters "a" and "b" from data:

```
Encrypting 2 characters using first method
data[0] is changing from 97 to <6>97
data[1] is changing from 98 to <6>98
```

I've never seen this type of output. What does this `<6>` thing mean and why can't I change the values?

Comment: If you don't put a newline on the end of the first `printk` then use `KERN_CONT` for the second `printk`. It is preferable to use a single `printk` per line of output.

Comment: In latest kernels v 4.x angle brackets no longer used for severity. The OP has something older.

Comment: In any case, the question is actually about **printing**, not about variable's modification as stated in the title and in the body.

Comment: It's not at all about printing. the values don't change. Do they?

Comment: What is `enc_key` ? If its `0` then results are correct. And how are you printing this statement when your print ends with `to` ?    `"data[%d] is changing from %d to "`